# Have you looked at the user rankings, lately?

Tags: discussion, reputation, beta, users

Jeff Atwood is about to drop off from page 1.

This is interesting because 1) he's a founder 2) it shows how other, active users are getting rep points!

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I keep seeing answers from people I don't recognize :) It's a good sign!

Comment: I've been wearing out my voting button.

Comment: What I found interesting looking at Area 51 the other day, was that "The How-To Geek" proposed this site, and then doesn't seem to have ever even logged in here, he's missed out on a nice shiny gold Founder badge! To be fair to Jeff he's got a decent number of points for someone who doesn't even own an Android phone AFAIK

Comment: I just hit the daily rep cap for the first time :)

Comment: no only does Jeff not own an android phone, he once said on twitter that android has about as much chance of making it as linux on the desktop.